# issue while upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04, software-center

There were several issues I faced while upgrading.

While updating there were some errors that came up but it was still upgrading. After some time I had a option of `Y` or `N`, I chose `N` for the default version.

It turned out to be 16.04, after I had to shut down my computer myself, because it did not restart, as it should after upgrading.

Secondly after the login page came, there began a loop, which had a black screen occurring every time I entered my password. I did not how to solve it, so I shutdown my laptop forcefully by pressing the power button. I had no idea what to do, so I restored back to my Ubuntu 14.04 factory state.

1. Please tell me whether I should again go for upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04, or should I wait for 16.04.1 as it said on few websites?
2. If the login page comes again, how should I solve it out?
3. If there are errors coming while upgrading, how should I solve them, or still let it upgrade, even though we cant do anything while it is upgrading?
4. Is it fine if I am using Ubuntu 14.04 rather than upgrading it? Because I just bought my laptop (Dell Inspiron 3558, which has only Intel graphics), two days ago, and I have no prior experience in Ubuntu, but in just two days I haven't done anything because of so many errors and broken packages stuff. Frankly, they are quite irritating.

Please answer, it wold be really nice so that I can decide to upgrade or not, and continue using Ubuntu.

Comment: What are the specs of your computer, especially the video card?

Comment: And 14.04 is supported until early 2018.

Comment: i have the normal intel video card,i just bought it for coding purposes.

Comment: @What command did you use to initiate the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

In case something bad happens next time, you can almost always drop into "text mode" by pressing Ctrl + Shift + F1 (or F2 or F3 or F4). It can take a second, so don't be too hasty. Mostly you can go back to your graphical session using Ctrl + Shift + F7 if it is working. You can fix most things in that simple terminal then. For tabs in the terminal, I use tmux and for very simple, text based browsing w3m or lynx (just as a tip), so make sure, you have them installed.

In your case, I would wait for the 16.04.1 release, since the initial bugs, like for specific hardware and upgrade circumstances, get fixed there. That point release also gets offered to users of the previous LTS release.

You can read more here: [How do I upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801488/how-do-i-upgrade-from-14-04-lts-to-16-04-1-lts)