# How do I upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04, lts, do-release-upgrade

So, today is July 21st and [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server). gives me an option to download 16.04.1 LTS. However, attempting to upgrade gets me this message -

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

What is wrong? Does it matter that I am running apt-get update behind `apt-cacher-ng`?

**Note:** Commenting out the files in apt.conf.d that used `apt-cacher-ng` did not make a difference.

**Edit: Explanation for possible duplicates:** [Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next) deals with upgrade from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS. My question is specific to 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS upgrade. Old answers, while good for archival purposes are less relevant in a fast changing package like ubuntu. Moreover none of the answers answer what is wrong. The link [andrew.46](https://askubuntu.com/users/57576/andrew-46) pointed out is mentioned in one of the comments. This Q & A is more helpful for people upgrading today than the work around mentioned in "[Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next)".

Comment: Hmmm..... from elsewhere on Ask Ubuntu: try `do-release-upgrade -d` or `update-manager -d`  http://askubuntu.com/q/125392/57576

Comment: I have not been able to upgrade yet either (without the -d, it works fine with that).

Comment: @andrew.46 - in the `-d` going to get me to 16.04.1? or just 16.04? I should not have to install the development release, should I?

Comment: @LordLoh.I have added some more info to a formal answer. Remember that 16.04.1 is simply the original release plus all of the latest updates added in. Same as installing the release 16.04 and then running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Finally, seems this bug has been fixed!

Comment: @LordLoh. Seems to be finally resolved :)

Comment: :-) Just noticed. Will run an upgrade once I reach home :-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is an issue that has appeared before: 4 years ago when upgrading from 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) to 14.04.1 LTS (Trusty Tahr):

- [Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](https://askubuntu.com/q/125392/57576)

It looks like *a similar issue* exists for the upgrade from 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) to 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus) with [the relevant update log](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts) not yet updated. There is a choice of *two* reasonable solutions at the moment:

1. Wait a little until this document is updated and then upgrade as normal
2. Use the following syntax *now*:

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade --devel-release
   ```

[Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html#do-release-upgrade) speaks on this option of using the `--devel-release` or `-d` option:

> For further stability of a LTS release there is a slight change in
>   behaviour if you are currently running a LTS version. LTS systems are
>   only automatically considered for an upgrade to the next LTS via
>   do-release-upgrade with the first point release. So for example 14.04
>   will only upgrade once 16.04.1 is released. If you want to update
>   before, e.g. on a subset of machines to evaluate the LTS upgrade for
>   your setup the same argument as an upgrade to a dev release has to be
>   used via the -d switch.

And certainly at the moment this should be a safe course to take. When undertaken on my own Trusty system:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
[sudo] password for andrew: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
andrew@corinth:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade --devel-release
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,265 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,265 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'xenial.tar.gz' against 'xenial.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'xenial.tar.gz'
[...]
```

And the process rolls on installing Xenial by utlising [this alternative file](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts-development). A few hints at upcoming resolution of this issue:

1. A few enquiries in IRC (thanks @ThomasWard) indicate imminent fixing of the issue pending the fixing of any bugs in the upgrade path...
2. A personal email to myself from a developer has indicated that this *should* be fixed in the week commencing July 25th
3. [A Launchpad bug and Feature Request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1605474) filed on this issue has some interesting comments...

Crossed fingers for a resolution soon!!

**Note**: *The [update log](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts) altered on July 29th my time, so issue now resolved...*

References:

- [Ubuntu Help Docs: do-release-upgrade](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html#do-release-upgrade)
- [Bharath/Lord Noh: "No new release found" upgrading from 14.04LTS to 16.04.1 [Bug + Feature Request]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1605474)

Comment: Is there a way to notify the maintainers about this?

Comment: Try a bug report from here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader

Comment: Thank you. Did that - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1605474

Comment: @LordLoh. Good on you!! I have added a link to this bug report from my answer.

Comment: Note that this is a case of the upgrade path not being enabled for another week, while bugs get squished and while things 'settle'; I asked this in the support rooms on IRC and got from-the-release-team answers stating this for the most part.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks for looking into this. Seems a pity that this question is heading for closure on the strength of a 4 year old question when this issue is of great interest and relevance to a more modern release. But I guess that is what 'Reopen' is for...

Comment: @ThomasWard I appreciate that you were able to find that out. It is frustrating that this information isn't more widely publicized, given the emphasis on how LTS releases should "just work".

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+question/303763 - I put in a feature request for a modifed error message. Something like - `No new release found. Next release expected on 2016-07-29`.

Comment: Just right now, as I speak, the 14.04.5 XOrg has moved from proposed to main, and the log has been updated!

Comment: So you all conclude that this issue is resolved now? I am still getting the same "No new release found " message when upgrading from 14.04.05 to 16.04.01.

Comment: I am as well, over 6 months on from the end of July. I'm still seeing "no new release found" when attempting to upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was not `-d` but rather `-p`. Maybe this is helpful for some of you encountering this problem.

Edit to explain (from `man do-release-upgrade`):

```
-d, --devel-release
              Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible

-p, --proposed
              Try upgrading to the latest  release  using  the  upgrader  from
              Ubuntu-proposed
```

`do-release-upgrade` has several useful switches. Reviewing the man page is always a good idea.