# My Ubuntu LTS cannot find Xenial's point release

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, point-release

I'm on 14.04 LTS. 16.04.1 is supposed to be out, but this is what I get in the command line:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I have no idea where to start investigating this. Why can't my Ubuntu find the upgrade?

EDIT: answers have been suggested saying I should try `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. I'm not sure I want to do that: I don't want to install the development version. Even if what this produces is not the installation of the development version but the installation of the point release (and I'm not sure I'll have any evidence of that until after the fact), I'm not sure I want to *request* the development version. I want to request a normal update. Also, this does not explain what's going on, nor does it solve it: it just bypasses it. If using `-d` is really the only solution available, I'll do it, but I'd much rather go to the root of the problem if I can.

EDIT 2: I ended up using the new `meta-release-lts` file solution.

Comment: I asked the same question http://askubuntu.com/questions/803308/16-04-1-is-out-but-still-no-new-release-found a few minutes ago.

Comment: This question and the accepted answer may help you out: http://askubuntu.com/q/801488/57576

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it – or in this case answer the linked question if your solution isn't listed there yet. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-)