# internal speaker is not working

Tags: sound, speakers

Just installed 14.04 on Dell Optiplex 7010 usff. The internal speaker is not working, BIOS audio test says audio is fine, audio out works.
Dell tech concludes it's a software problem. Have reset the defaults in BIOS and passed all BIOS diagnostic tests. What to do?

I ran `alsactl restore`, and got this:

```
alsactl: state_lock:121: file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state lock error: File exists
alsactl: load_state:1677: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: File exists
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Intel PantherPoint HDMI" "HDA:10ec0269,10280577,00100100 HDA:80862806,80860101,00100000" "0x1028" "0x0577"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
savanne@savanne-HP-ProBook-4720s:~$
```

This HD was originally in a HP laptop. I put the HD in the Optiplex without reinstalling 14.04, it seems to be working fine except for the internal speaker.

Comment: Did you update all packages with `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`? You also should consider [upgrading to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801488/how-do-i-upgrade-from-14-04-lts-to-16-04-1-lts).

Answer (score 0):

yes, I already did the updates, and also installed 16.04 on another partition. Still no internal speaker.  Might just add that in 16.04 Firefox runs very poorly; it runs so slow that I can't stream videos.