# apt-get dist-upgrade does not upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my computer. I am using `apt-get`. This is the command I am typing:

```
root@alphabeta:~# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I am confused. I cannot understand why `apt-get` does not download a newer version of Xubuntu 16.04, Xenial Xerus LTS from the Xubuntu 17.04, Zesty Zapus and install xubuntu upgrade.

I have updated my repositories before trying to use the command line argument apt-get update.

The links that are associated to not answer my question I do not think it is a problem with my repository I do not understand why apt-get returned  saying there was nothing to upgrade: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0  not upgraded, the only thing I thought to do is clean my cache.

I would really like a better answer the information I received from asking about disk formatting with hdparm was excellent.

aptitude is nt my forte I learn as I go like lsof I cannot remember all the command line arguments.

Comment: Related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/801488/how-do-i-upgrade-from-14-04-lts-to-16-04-1-lts/938985#938985

Comment: Run `apt-get update` first to update repository database.

Comment: Are you currently running [Zesty](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes) or are you running a previous release? If so which release?

Answer (score 9):

The preferred way to upgrade Xubuntu to the newest LTR version is to do:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The manual way you were attempting can be used to upgrade to any version you desire. however, some manual clean up is required after because apt-get will try to resolve the upgrade with the minimal amount of removals.
To manually upgrade:

First run: `apt-mark showhold` to be sure nothing is being held back.
If you find held packages then remove the hold and update them I find `aptitude` is the easiest way for marking and updating multiple packages at one time. Aptitude will also suggest removal of orphaned packages (packages that are no longer used by anything).
`sudo apt-get autoremove` will also remove packages that are no longer used.

After your system is fully up to date in the current version, change you sources to point to the version of Xubuntu that you want.
EX: change "trusty" to 'xenial"

Next run this series of commands:

`sudo apt-get update` This updates the package list
`sudo apt-get upgrade` This upgrades packages that can be upgraded without changing other packages. thus easing the dependency resolving in the next step.
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` This upgrades the remaining packages that can be upgraded with a minimal amount of removals.

You now have the new version of Xubuntu, and need to clean up obsoleted packages. Again I find `aptitude` to be the easiest way to do this.
Open aptitude and it will already have a list of suggested removals (orphaned packages), it is generally safe to remove them.
Now go through the remaining obsolete packages. In most cases, remaining packages have been replaced with another: ie gt4 with gt5 and gstreamer0.1-good with gstreamer1.0-good. The replacements will be under the heading of new packages.
This step is the most critical and why I like `aptitude`, replacing the obsoleted packages will often break other packages; however the broken package usually also has a replacement package to correct dependencies.
`Aptitude` will list broken packages and recommend fixes. Check over actions to be performed before committing to them.

When you have finish, clean your package cache:
`sudo apt-get autoclean` this will remove the package cache for packages that are no longer used.

Comment: are you saying that packages reported as being kept back is what is causing do-release-update to tell me I need to install all available updates first, while trying to upgrade tells me there is nothing to do?

Comment: and why are packages marked to be kept back? i didn't do it, is it possible that not doing so will break something?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Installs the newest kernel and anything else that is held back by a normal `apt-get upgrade`. Perhaps you are looking for:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` isn't just kernels. it will update/upgrade everything to the newest version available in the repositories. To do what he wants, his source lists must first be pointed to a newer version of ubuntu.

Comment: @ravery Forgive me, but I've never done an in-place upgrade before: Why would OP have to point his source lists to a newer version?

Comment: @ravery edited.

Comment: @wjandrea -- OP was trying to upgrade via the debian method. this answer incorrectly says that `sudo dist-ugrade` only upgrade kernel. If the sources are not changed nothing will be upgraded.

Comment: @ravery But that's why Ubuntu has `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @AndroidDev Yeah, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @AndroidDev -- exactly, though I have had some desaters with it. Ubuntu has automated the various steps of upgrading with one command `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @ravery Oh. Then I'm still confused. Why would OP have to change his source lists?

Comment: If there's an easier way of doing something, why make the OP do it the hard way?

Comment: to upgrade via `apt-get update`,`apt-get upgrade`, then `apt-get dist-upgrade` the sources first have to point to the version of ubuntu that you want to upgrade to. Actually this method could be used to change to any debian based linux... as one poster had done, he changed his distro to kali

Comment: @AndroidDev I am not making him do it the hard way, just pointing out why he didn't succeed, he forgot a step. and the error in your original statement.. the automated way has had some dependency chain disasters that has resulted in complete removal of the desktop. maybe the OP wants to do the manual way